# asp.net mvc kendo ui grid encrypt column data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc

```
    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            height: 430,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
            "ProductName", {
                field: "ID",
                title: "Product ID",
                width: "100px"
                }, {
                field: "UnitPrice",
                title: "Unit Price",
                format: "{0:c}",
                width: "100px"
                }, {
                field: "UnitsInStock",
                title: "Units In Stock",
                width: "100px"
                }, {
                field: "Discontinued",
                width: "100px"
                }, {
                command: ["edit", "destroy"],
                title: " ",
                width: "172px"
            }
            ],
            editable: "inline"
        }).data("kendoGrid");
```

How can i encrypt column Product ID on kendo ui grid for user can't see my real id ? I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct Encrypting you can use kendo grid client Template for the column where you pass the Id value to the javascript function encrypt it using your algorithm and then returning it.
 something like.

```
columns.Bound(client => client.Id).ClientTemplate("#=Encrypt(Id)#");
```

And

```
 <script> 
function Encrypt(id)
{
// Logic to Encrypt ID
return encryptedID.toString();
}
</script>
```

If this is just to show to the users then this solutions works

and second solution is to just hide the column (i mean there is no use of showing ids to the user)

If you find this helpful please mark as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Enrcypt data before you load data in your code behind after that bind your data.

In order to do this use a class for encrpyt as below

```
public class DataEncryptor
{
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider symm;

    #region Factory
    public DataEncryptor()
    {
        this.symm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        this.symm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    }
    public DataEncryptor(TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider keys)
    {
        this.symm = keys;
    }

    public DataEncryptor(byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        this.symm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        this.symm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        this.symm.Key = key;
        this.symm.IV = iv;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider Algorithm
    {
        get { return symm; }
        set { symm = value; }
    }
    public byte[] Key
    {
        get { return symm.Key; }
        set { symm.Key = value; }
    }
    public byte[] IV
    {
        get { return symm.IV; }
        set { symm.IV = value; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Crypto

    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data) { return Encrypt(data, data.Length); }
    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, int length)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a MemoryStream.
            var ms = new MemoryStream();

            // Create a CryptoStream using the MemoryStream 
            // and the passed key and initialization vector (IV).
            var cs = new CryptoStream(ms,
                symm.CreateEncryptor(symm.Key, symm.IV),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            // Write the byte array to the crypto stream and flush it.
            cs.Write(data, 0, length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();

            // Get an array of bytes from the 
            // MemoryStream that holds the 
            // encrypted data.
            byte[] ret = ms.ToArray();

            // Close the streams.
            cs.Close();
            ms.Close();

            // Return the encrypted buffer.
            return ret;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A cryptographic error occured: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public string EncryptString(string text)
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)));
    }

    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data) { return Decrypt(data, data.Length); }
    public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, int length)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a new MemoryStream using the passed 
            // array of encrypted data.
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);

            // Create a CryptoStream using the MemoryStream 
            // and the passed key and initialization vector (IV).
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms,
                symm.CreateDecryptor(symm.Key, symm.IV),
                CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            // Create buffer to hold the decrypted data.
            byte[] result = new byte[length];

            // Read the decrypted data out of the crypto stream
            // and place it into the temporary buffer.
            cs.Read(result, 0, result.Length);
            return result;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A cryptographic error occured: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public string DecryptString(string data)
    {
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(data))).TrimEnd('\0');
    }

    #endregion

}
```

and use it like this:

```
string message="A very secret message here.";
DataEncryptor keys=new DataEncryptor();
string encr=keys.EncryptString(message);

// later
string actual=keys.DecryptString(encr);
```